# JavaScript- properties and variables

Tags: javascript, memory

In my code I was to deleting custom-objects. I realized, we can not delete objects which are declared using 'var'. (after reading this documentation [Delete operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)).

- Most of my objects are declared and initialized using 'var'. They can't be deleted in single delete statement(unless I loop through it and delete each property.)
  I can set them to 'null'.
- My custom objects are relatively bigger in size (may block considerable chunk of memory.

For better memory management and performance should I use 'properties' or 'variables' to store my objects? Will it make a difference?

Please provide any references for better insight on 'properties' and 'variables' in javascript.

```
globalProp = {//can be deleted, it is a 'property' to global object.
'name': 'Mia',
'age': 34,
'sex': 'F'
};

var globalVar = {//can not be deleted with delete statement, it is variable of global object
'name': 'Lia',
'age': 25,
'sex': 'F'
};
```

(In above code, we can refer to globalProp as 'window.globalProp' but can't refer to globalVar as window.globalVar.)

[Have fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mundie/ude3G/)

Comment: Corrected one statement in my question.

Comment: In javascript you can usually let the garbage collector take care of disposing of your objects and you almost never need to use the `delete` operator. Why are you so worried about memory management? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I make a call to web service based on the options selected by user. I get lot information which I parse and store in an object. This information is further used to plot a graph on the web page. ... user is further allowed keep on changing his options, every time I fetch new info from web service. I want to delete objects that are created...

Comment: In the end its all a matter of making sure that you get rid of all references pointing to your object. If the variables pointing to the object are in a function they will go out of scope when the function finishes so often there is nothing you need to do. If you are using global variables then setting the variables to a different value (such as null) should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has runtime and garbage collector with some complex cleaning and managing algorithms, any try to interfere or speed them will proably do the opposite, resulting some runtime penalty. it is the best to leave the memory managment to the underlying runtime.

however, there are some points that you might want to consider:
1) avoid global variables as much as possible. this is a good advice for any language that support global/static variables. global variables means global references with no scope - the referenced object will live on as long as the (global) reference holds it. this danger increases even more if the global variable is an array or object which keeps on appending children to itself. 
this is the common case which leads to a memory leak in managed languages
2) avoid cyclic references - don't make one member variable point to a different object, and that object holds a member which points to the first object. this will make a hard time for the garbage collector.
3) write clean, simple, maintainable code. this may seems as unrelated preach, but an easier, short, maintainable code will probably enhance the interperter/compiler ability to optimize the code.
4) don't assume nothing about how the code affects the speed. there are so many layers down there that you can't simply assume anything. benchmark the code to get real facts.
5) don't optimize unless you need to (you probably don't).

so for your question : declare anything with `var` as much as possible. declaring a variable with `var` will make them local - when the function ends the reference will get out of scope and the GC can start determine the destruction time for the object earlier. declaring your object without `var` will make them global - it is unclear when will the GC decide to delete the object, thus slowing things down.
and as you know - declaring variables global can lead to many bugs, keep things scoped. don't use `delete`. it's just wrong.